# LEDs and voltage optimisation

Tags: led, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

I am looking for some advice.

I understand that LED drivers transform a supply from AC to DC as well as the amount of volts from input to output, for this reason i believe they are classed as inductive loads.( these are not inductive, these are non-linear resistive loads)

Will there be an increase in efficiency using LEDS on a site with voltage optimisation and if so what would the average increase in efficiency be. Just so you know there will be a lot of 22w LED tubes.

I want to say they voltage optimisation will increase effiency but im not sure if it will be worth it considering the buy back time and the fact there are minimal inductive loads on site.

Thank you in advance for any replies

Liam

ps. £60,000 for voltage optimiser
    2000 LED lamps on site average 22w

Comment: LEDs are not inductive loads, they do not store energy in a magnetic field.

Comment: Thanks Jlm, Is this the case with all electronic ballasts/ drivers?

Comment: And does this mean they are purely a resistive load?

Comment: They act as a non-linear resistive load (they are diodes after all). In the reverse direction they are effectively open circuit and in the forward direction they effectively switch to a small (non-linear) resisitance once the forward voltage has been exceeded. That's why you either need to use a current controlled supply or use a fixed resistor to limit the maximum current.

Comment: Do you intend to replace about 2000 TL lamps with these tubes? In that case the drivers are inside the tubes. With that quantity you need to change something because of the socalled third harmonic comming from the drivers. So first we need to know what you exactly plan to do

Comment: Perhaps I should also add that LEDs don't take a lot of reverse voltage before they breakdown (avalanche effect) so its not a good idea to use them to convert AC to DC without adding some extra (ordinary) diodes.

Comment: yes we do intend to change these around 2000 TL lamps with LED tubes( a simple retrofit). This will happen across 3 separate mains supply's and there for we would be installing three voltage optimisers(but only if there as a sufficient efficiency increase). Am i right in saying the only benefit would be the voltage optimiser slightly reversing the effects of harmonics and this would slightly increase power factor, and if this is correct, would it be nessacary if a PFC un it was installed on the supply already?

Comment: Please bare in mind the florescents existing have ELECTRONIC ballasts which are non-linear loads and produce harmonics also

also, i am including the manufactorers drivers inbuiltin the tubes here. im not looking to alter anything in the way of installation apart from possibly installing a voltage optimiser at the main supply unless anything i have suggested will be problematic. Thanks for the advice all

Comment: Complete .......................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Voltage optimisation**" - essentially reducing mains voltage so that it is at a lower voltage than average, is almost certain to be a waste of money and have negative rate of return in your application.

- ie In most applications VO is expensive snake oil. In a very few it may be worthwhile BUT you need to know why and design the system well. In almost all cases, don't even think about it.

In your application they are almost certainly of no value because an LED tube's inbuilt power supply is designed to operate the LEDs at a designed operating point and designed power level. To do this the supply takes the available mains voltage and draws whatever energy is needed to operate the LEDs correctly. If the mains voltage is increased the current drawn will decrease proportionately. Similarly, if the mains voltage is decreased the current drawn will increase proportionately. In each case the input power will be essentially the same.

I say "essentially" as the efficiency of the mains AC to LED drive converter will probably vary somewhat as mains voltage varies - but this will vary with design and possibly amongst inits of the same model, and the worst case differences are liable to be small.

It is possible but unlikely that the tubes that you are buying have a significantly greater efficiency at some input voltages than others. In this unlikely event the optimum voltage may be at the low end or high end or at the average expeccted mains voltage. This would be due NOT for the reasons that voltage optimisers are claimed to work for (lower Vin = lower power draw) which can apply in SOME special cases, but due to manufacturing and design issues that the voltage optimiser maker is unaware oif and unable to design for.

If you really care you could take say 10 tubes and operate then from a variac from Vmin_allowed to Vmax_allowed in say 10% steps and see if there is any useful change in efficiency for a single tube and, if so, if this is consistent across the samples tested. It is extremelt likely that this will prove that a voltage optimiser serves no useful purpose here.

---

**VO's and PFCs**

Voltage Optimisers have some overlap with PFCs = but usually not much.

Simplistic mains AC to LED drive circuits tend to draw high current at mains voltage peaks and lower current as voltage drops in a cycle and then probably no power for much of the ranage around zero crossing.
This leads to large current peaks at voltage peaks and no current for a large part of the cycle. This can be "deconstructed" as a current waveform rich in harmonics - the end effect is effectively low power factor and violation of regulatory standards aimed at exactly this issue as electronic loads increase. To meet standards modern LED drivers incorporate waveform correction circuitry - also able to be seen as power factor correction circuitry, which converts the current drain to essentially mains frequency sinusoidal with less than an allowed amount of distortion.
A "good" voltage optimiser may well deal with peaky loads as a part of its voltage shifting task. Failure to do so would make them unsuited to some roles due to regulatory non-compliance. This is no guarantee that they actually will behave as desired. If the load already draws essentially sinusoidal current the VO serves no purpose in that area and probably little or none on any other.

---

**Related:**

[VO - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_optimisation)

[Jeff Howell - fergetaboutit](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/property/advice/9153868/Jeff-Howells-DIY-advice-home-voltage-optimisers.html)

[Some real tests - Bzzzzzzt](http://www.yougen.co.uk/blog-entry/1948/Is+domestic+voltage+optimisation+all+it'27s+cracked+up+to+be'3F/)

Comment: Am i right in saying that the higher the supply voltage the less current an LED driver will draw therefore making it cheaper?

Comment: That just doesnt seem right, please correct me if i have mis interpreted what you have said

Comment: Ahhh, the rest of the post has appeared now, please ignore my last 2 comments

Comment: I've added more (I hadn't finished) which may help. | Usually power is what you are charged for. So as V rises I drops but power ~= the same so $ the same || Note- reactive loads MAY affect this. You are charged either for power = watts = v x I at unity power factor OR for VA = reactive power - the latter usually only in large industrial situations. Power drops for given VA as power factor decreases. Feeders must be dimensioned on peak amps regardless of power which is why low PF is disliked by power companies.

Comment: You are my hero.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that the supply of the lamps are distributed over 3 phases. Since the socalled third harmonic of the lamps cause a large current in the neutral.( not balanced out) extra measures might be required to keep the current density within limits. Do not confuse the power factor with the influence of the harmonics